# Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt' when I do a big table

Tags: android, stack

I am doing an app with a table.
Each row have 3 textview and the rows are generated dynamically.

All work good but when the rows are more than 15-20 i see this message in logcat(about 3 times):

```
09-24 15:48:37.307: I/dalvikvm(32685): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-24 15:48:37.337: I/dalvikvm(32685): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

(the table take some seconds to show up, more row it have more time to show).

Is there a solution to avoid this problem or it is normal for big table?

This is the code that generate the table:

```
for (Esame e : Db.risposteDate){

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        TextView lbl1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView lbl2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView lbl3 = new TextView(this);
        tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        lbl1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lbl3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        lbl1.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        lbl2.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        lbl3.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);

        lbl1.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );
        lbl2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 7 ) );
        lbl3.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );

        lbl1.setText(e.getDomandaNum()+"");
        lbl2.setText(Html.fromHtml(e.getTesto()+"<br />"));
        lbl3.setText(e.getRispostaData());

        tr.addView(lbl1);
        tr.addView(lbl2);
        tr.addView(lbl3);
        tl.addView(tr);

}
```

Comment: ANR is normal if you do stuff in the UI thread that takes longer than a few ms - prepare the data to display in a background thread to avoid that.

Comment: i did a thread and put the for loop, but nothing changed. can you explain better the "prepare the data to display in a background thread to avoid that."